# what is "do_shortcode" in wordpress and how it works?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently learning wordpress theme development and for better understanding I have downloaded couple of wordpress theme and seeing their code.
But a line of code I can't understand. here it is-->

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(sq_option( 'footer_text ' ' ')); ?>
```

maybe its for footer but how this works and how i can use this function when I will create my own.

Comment: I can't see your code?

Answer (score 2):

Generally `do_shortcode();` is use to get data from shortcode or its attribute to your PHP code or to filter any shortcode returning data. Shortcode can be provided by any plugin.

Not sure about it but in your theme's code `sq_option("footer_text");` could be a function which is filtering some text from footer.

The code could be as:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="quote"]' ); ?>`

**[Reference Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And one more thing what is sq_option doing here?

Comment: As I said `sq_option` could be a function in your theme that are filtering some data from a shortcode related to your footer. It might be for footer widget as it depends on your theme.

Answer (score 2):

do_shortcode () is usefull function-> for excute shortcode in template file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before answering an old question having an other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

do_shortcode is a function you have to use if you want to execute a shortcode inside a custom theme template page see more info on the function here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/